# Make several classes have the same attributes without inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm facing a problem in Java.

I need to have several classes with the same attributes ( for example a Position and a boolean isWalkable ).

But I don't want these classes to inherit from a class Element because that would prevent me from using inheritance later.

I thought of an interface (so that the interface has the attributes), but apparently you can't have an interface inherit from a class.

There must be a way because otherwise I would have to copy/paste my attributes and there methods.

Thanks in advance for anyone who has an idea on how to overcome this problem.

Comment: *but apparently you can't have an interface inherit from a class*: why would you want that? You want classes to implement your interface instead. You won't be able to share attributes, though. Only method signatures.

Comment: What about composition?  Design a wrapper class that can reference both your actual classes, as well as your position and isWalkable fields and then refer to that elsewhere in your code.

Comment: So each of my classes would have an attribut Element which is the wrapper class you suggest ?

Comment: That is an option.

What I was envisioning is something like an ElementWrapper class that has one field of type Element (containing your position and isWalkable attributes), and another field called wrappedInstance (or something like that), referring to the actual object that is dependent on the element data.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't understand what the field "wrappedInstance" would be for, could you explain ?

Comment: If you can give me some more insight into what the classes will do, I can try and put together some example code to illustrate what I mean.  What is an example of a class in your application that would require the parameters that you need, but without extending an Element class?

Comment: I'm doing a multi agent system for a school project.

Comment: Sorry misclick. 
This multi agent system is for an Anthill. 

I would have a map, with different elements (food source, ants, obstacles ect). So each  of these class must have the attributes position and isWalkable. However Ant, for exemple, will need to inherit from another class.

Comment: Copy, paste, enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you might need **an interface anyway**, if you want to treat your objects generically - e.g. loop over all of them and draw each one. E.g. assuming your elements include "cats" and "houses":

```
interface Element{
   public point getPosition();
   public boolean isWalkable();
}
class Cat implements Element{
   private Point position;
   private String catBreed; // example of cat-specific data
   public point getPosition() {return position;}
   public boolean isWalkable() {return true;} // cats can walk
   ...
}
class House implements Element{
   private Point position;
   private String streetAddress; // example of house-specific data
   public point getPosition() {return position;}
   public boolean isWalkable() {return false;} // houses cannot walk  
   ..
}

// Finally, using that common interface:
Element[] allGameObjects= {new Cat(...), new Cat(...), new House(...) };
for(Element e:allGameObjects) 
   draw(e, e.getPosition());
```

That was good enough for several system I wrote... but as other replies correctly mentioned, you might refactor to use composition - however it might not be a 100% clear-cut. I mean, I can understand if you feel Cat or House should be managed independently from their position... but what about isWalkable?

```
// Position is easy to separate:
class Cat { String catBreed; ... }
class House{ String streetAddress; ... }

class ElementWrapper implements Element{
   Point position;
   Object  theObject; // could hold Cat or House
   public Point getPosition() {return position;}
   // however, isWalkable is a bit tricky... see remark below
}
```

But 'isWalkable' is tricky because in classic polymorphism you'd expect House/Cat to tell you whether they can walk (meaning they should implement an interface anyway). If you absolutely don't want (or cant) have it, you may compromise on polymorphism and do something in the lines of instanceof (if theObject is instanceof Cat then it can walk, if it's instanceof House it cannot walk, etc).

Answer (score 1):

For this, I would consider [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AgentWrapper agentWrapper = new AgentWrapper(new Agent1(), false, 1);
        System.out.println("isWalkable: " + agentWrapper.isWalkable());
        System.out.println("position: " + agentWrapper.getPosition());
        agentWrapper.getAgent().doSomething();
    }
}

interface Agent {
    void doSomething();
}

class Agent1 implements Agent {

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Agent1");
    }
}

class Agent2 implements Agent {

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Agent1");
    }
}

class AgentWrapper {

    private final Agent agent;  //Wrapped instance.
    private final boolean isWalkable;
    private final int position;

    public AgentWrapper(Agent agent, boolean isWalkable, int position) {
        this.agent = agent;
        this.isWalkable = isWalkable;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Agent getAgent() {
        return agent;
    }

    public boolean isWalkable() {
        return isWalkable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend an abstract base class(containing nothing) or You can use the Decorator pattern as somebody suggested in the comments, for more information related to Decorator pattern you can read this  [link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=258).